# How to access an specific child that has a unique ID in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am new using Firebase. I am building an iOS app and I am confused about how to retrieve values from the database and how to make my database realtime.

There is an specific situation that I don’t know how to solve. In my current app, I can create notes and store them in Firebase database. These notes are displayed in a tableView. When you click one of the cells you can modify the note. Every note contains a title, a date and a message. So when you want to update a note. How can I keep track of the note being updated so that I can create the correct path to call the correct child from Firebase?

I am using updateChildValues function.

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
Notes
    |
    a7Uzr64jhBNpEbCkOufUNRxHeZv1   (userID)
          | 
          -KJlc7cqlBUEvWGjhfnj     (messageID)
              |
              date: "Jun 8, 2016, 2:07 PM"
              message: "Testing notes! "
              title: "front_raises"
          -KJlbzmYVDKTiRUmxVsAaddclose
              |
              date: "Jun 8, 2016, 2:06 PM"
              message: "Recovering! "
              title: "batter_on_deck"}
```

So the JSON tree start with Notes, then it has a child that is a unique ID for every user. Then there is the message unique id that contains date, message and title for the note.

so if I want to retrieve and update the values of the second event how can I do that?

Each message have a unique ID. Im using ChildAutoID. Therefore, I am wondering, if I have saved more than 1 message, and I want to update one of those messages, how can I retrieve from Firebase that specific message?

Right now I have this but I don't want to pass that specific uniqueid string. I want to pass a variable that would contain the uniqueId of the current message I want to modify.

```
 [[[_dbReference child:_current_user.uid] child:@"-KJglUt2UguG8jw5Jp_K"] setValue:@{@"title": newData[1], @"date": newData[2], @"message": newData[0]}];
```

First child is current_user_uid. The second child, I am using the uniqueID created by ChildAutoID. 
So how can I get that uniqueID so that when I retrieve from Firebase I can use that value to refer to the child and get the message I want?

Here is how I save the message:

```
- (IBAction)saveMessageButton:(id)sender {

  if([_messageTextView.text isEqualToString:@""]){
  _messageTextView.text = @"empty message";
  }
  if([_messageNameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    _messageNameTextField.text = @"No name";
  }
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *message = [self.messageTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"%%"];
    message = [message stringByAppendingString:self.messageNameTextField.text];
    message = [message stringByAppendingString:@"%%"];
    message = [message stringByAppendingString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]];

    // ******** Firebase ************ //
    NSArray *newMessage = [message componentsSeparatedByString:@"%%"];

    //creates a unique ID for every new message created
    NSString *key = [[_dbReference child:@"Messages"] childByAutoId].key;


    NSDictionary *theMessage = @{@"title": newMessage[1],
                                 @"date": newMessage[2],
                                 @"message": newMessage[0]
                                };

    NSString *newPath = @"/";
    newPath = [newPath stringByAppendingString:_current_user.uid];
    newPath = [newPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

    NSString *path = [newPath stringByAppendingString:key];
    NSDictionary *addingMessage = @{path: theMessage };

    [_dbReference updateChildValues:addingMessage];

    // ********End of Firebase ********* //

    NSString *messages = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"messages"];

    // If this is the first message saved
    if(messages == nil || [messages isEqualToString:@""]){
        messages = message;
    }
    else{
        messages = [messages stringByAppendingString:@"^^"];
        messages = [messages stringByAppendingString:message];
    }
    [userDefaults setObject:messages forKey:@"messages"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show the code you already have please. Without that, the best we can do is write an entire app for you or point you to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: I added the code and added a small explanation about my problem.